# C# Custom control causes CS0436 warning and designer of to not show

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, windows-forms-designer

i am working on a project to make postits and print tasks on them. Just for the sake of learning the language. I want to put everything in classes, and build the project up, from these classes.

So, to start I created a class called postit in a seperate file. The file is imported in the project somehow by VS2019, so I am able to see the control in the toolbox. I can drag and drop the postit just fine, but then after some time, out of nowhere, the designer crashes.

The code runs fine if I run it in debugger mode and behaives as expected (selecting, moving etc). but the designer from VS2019 is showing a bunch of complains in the following error message "**Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.**" and showing the warning CS0436 on the location where the designer code calls the class. This is a sort of type mismatch warning as I understood. Which makes no sense to me, since I created only one place where a type called postit is created. How does this work?

Here is my code of the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace Digipi.CustomControls
{
    public class Postit : Panel
    {
        //Fields
        public Color BGColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFAA");
        private Color HoverColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFAAAA");
        private Color LineColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#AAAAFF");
        private int startLineX = 10;
        private int startLineY = 20;
        public int lineInterval = 2;
        public Color borderColor =Color.Black;
        public int nrLines=5;
        public int SelectionThickness =10;
        private Point MouseDownLocation;
        private bool moving = false;
        private bool selected = false;

        //Properties
        [Category("PostIt adjustments")]
        public Color BackgroundColor
        {
            get
            {
                return BGColor;
            }
            set
            {
                BGColor = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        [Category("PostIt adjustments")]
        public int SelectionBorder
        {
            get
            {
                return SelectionThickness;
            }
            set
            {
                SelectionThickness = value;
                this.Invalidate();
            }
        }
        //Constructor
        public Postit()
        {
            MinimumSize = new Size(50, 10);
            BackColor = BGColor;
        }

        //Methods
        private GraphicsPath Outline(bool border, float thickness=0)
        {
            GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();
            GP.StartFigure();
            GP.AddLine(thickness,thickness,this.Width-thickness,thickness);
            GP.AddLine(this.Width - thickness, thickness, this.Width - thickness, this.Height - thickness);
            GP.AddLine(this.Width - thickness, this.Height - thickness,thickness,this.Height-thickness);
            GP.CloseFigure();
            return GP;
        }

        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnClick(e);
            this.selected = true;
            /*foreach pi in this.Parent.Controls{

            }*/
            this.Invalidate();
        }
        protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //base.OnMouseDown(e);
            if (this.moving)
            {
                return;
            }
            this.moving = true;
            this.MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
            

        }

        protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseMove(e);
            if (!this.moving)
            {
                return;
            }
            //Point p = new Point(Cursor.Position.X - this.OffsetPoint.X, Cursor.Position.Y - this.OffsetPoint.Y);
            
            this.Left = e.X+this.Left-MouseDownLocation.X;
            this.Top = e.Y + this.Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
        }

        protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseUp(e);
            this.moving = false;
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);
            e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            Brush b = new SolidBrush(BGColor);
            e.Graphics.FillPath(b, Outline(false));
            Pen pLine = new Pen(LineColor, 1);
            Pen pBorder = new Pen(borderColor, SelectionThickness);
            int lines = (int)(this.Height - startLineY )/ lineInterval;
            for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawLine(pLine, startLineX, startLineY+i*lineInterval, (float)(this.Width * 0.9), startLineY + i * lineInterval);
            }
            if (this.selected){
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(pBorder, Outline(true, SelectionThickness / 2));
            }

        }
    }

    
}
```

Inserting the object is done via the designer drag and drop, so that is standard.

I really dont understand why the designer is crashing..

Comment: There are some objects that are not being disposed of.  Make sure you dispose of those objects when you are done with them.  `Pen`, `Brush`, `GraphicsPath`, possibly more.  Fix that and see if your issue persists.

Comment: Try this on VS 2022. It may be a bug already fixed.

Comment: You said "after a period of time", how long is the cycle? Did you check the comments above.

Comment: Hi, i think disposing the pens and brushes helped. I will try a couple days and answere on this comment so others will quicly see the fix to this issue. I think the memory gets overloaded by 'in use brushes' and so on? Thanks for the help so far at least!!

Comment: No luck so far. Again i am back at square one. I really don't get it!